# Android Storage Access Framework - How portable is DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

After years of developing my directory manager, I finally found how to modify sdcard files. This is by using Storage Access Framework, api level >= 21.

Problem is, DocumentsContract is highly undocumented.

I am using Android 7.0. and noticed that DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID is is a partial file system path

```
id = F6F5-1B1D:Download/download
filepath = /storage/F6F5-1BD/Download/download
```

This works in my benefit as instead of recursively query children Uri to match a filesystem path, I can just convert the document uri to its file system path.

My problem now is that MAYBE not all Android 7 devices will return this kind of Uri structure. I think I read that Android kitkat document id is an integer instead. Meanwhile Android 8 document id is same as the file system path.

Comment: Yes, saf uries can mostly be converted to a file system path. That is interesting. But what more? For what would you use such a path? You can do all with saf. On removable media using a path you only have read access. It brings nothing for me. Why do you want a path?

Comment: @blackapps good question. I am trying to implement Internal Storage with java.io.File and SdCard with SAF. In general I dont completely understand SAF, so I need to better understand it and see if I can simply use it for everything.

Comment: You should make a file explorer for all partitions. Primary, secundary (micro SD card) and usb otg. AND you should make a saf explorer for the same partitions.

Comment: @blackapps you asked why I needed a java.io.File. Well  I have been going through my code, trying implement SAF. java.io.File is well baked in! Anyhow, I have a file path branch view that allows users to click to any branch of the file path. This surely requires me to know the filepath instead of some opaque ID. Or come to think of it, I could just have a list of branch id(s) and assign each as a tag to my branch view. Then when I click a branch, I use the ID handle to open that branch path.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are doing. With ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you can let the user choose all partitions. Having a tree uri you can list all subdirs an files in it. Recursively. What do you need more? No need for paths.

Comment: @blackapps I hinted in my last comment I wasnt clear if I needed file paths. However now I see that I save a browse history to file and restore it when activity restarts. Since Uri is parcelable but not Serializable, how would I store it to file? I would have to use recursion to get path and recursion to get back the Uri is what I see. I still have alot to learn about SAF as I try to convert my java.io.File pudding code to fascilitate SAF.

Comment: `save a browse history to file` I have no idea what you want to store. And why would you store a history? If you want to use saf in combination with File class then you are on the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using Android 7.0. and noticed that DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID is is a partial file system path

For that particular device, for that particular document provider, for that particular document, that may be the case.

> My problem now is that MAYBE not all Android 7 devices will return this kind of Uri structure

It is not strictly tied to a OS version. For example, all Android 7 devices will return other structures for other document providers, such as Google Drive.

Beyond that, even for the external storage provider, this sort of behavior can be changed by:

- Google, in either OS versions or updates to system components via the Play Store
- Device manufacturers, if they supply their own implementation of this document provider
- Users, if they have installed custom firmware

Treat identifiers as opaque values. Do not make assumptions based on apparent patterns in their values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It wasn't an assumption but an hypothesis. But you clearly state, treat id as opaque values. May I ask if you read that in the Android standards?

Comment: @user13947194: "May I ask if you read that in the Android standards?" -- if by "that", you mean the idea of treating IDs as opaque values, not when I wrote it. I have been programming computers for over 35 years, and you learn lessons along the way. Now that I happen to look at [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/DocumentsContract.Document#column_document_id), though, it has "Unique ID of a document. This ID is both provided by and interpreted by a DocumentsProvider, and should be treated as an opaque value by client applications".

Comment: I finally implemented browsing with SAF. My problem now is opening files. Most 3rd party Activities dont support document uri. Thus I need to convert to content uri. But how? Note: If I am able to convert to content uri, I would at the same time be able to get the real file path.

Comment: @user13947194: "Most 3rd party Activities dont support document uri" -- that would be rather surprising, since it is been required for working with Gmail for years.

Comment: Try opening a file with intent ACTION_VIEW